# Is there a way to send a newsletter to those users who share a taxonomy term in there profile

Tags: taxonomy-terms, users, nodes, emails

I need to be able to collect newsletters for a specific type of content. This content will have tags that the user will also check on when the sign up or edit their account information. I then need to send this newsletter to all those associated with that taxonomy list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want something that simplenews doesnt do right out of the box. You can create newsletters ([and a block for subscription links](http://drupal.org/node/197057)) -- but it doesnt appear to based off of Taxonomy terms directly.

Simplenews supports [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules), you could maybe define rules that achieve your goal.

I have not used simplenews, but I have a website for student surveys which has various email templates that remind students if they have additional surveys to complete, all running off of cron tasks -- you could code this type of newsletter functionality by hand without many helper modules if need be.

Sometimes manipulating a contributed module to suite your needs is harder than just doing it yourself for your project.

Comment: could you share with me the code you used to achieve this functionality?

Comment: unfortunately I cannot share what code I have as its project specific and using system cron jobs and Drush.